# mysqldump. Location of the file?

Tags: sql, mysql

I did an update on my db, but can't find the file so I can download it. Where is the file located at? Thanks in advance

```
   root@xxxx:~# mysqldump -u root -p cherio > myBackup.sql
    Enter password: 
    root@xxxx:~# find myBackup.sql
    myBackup.sql
```

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
  root@xxxx:~# find / -name "myBackup.sql"
  /root/myBackup.sql
```

Ok, I had to refresh my FTP for the file to show up.

Comment: The prompt `root@xxx:~#` says your file is in root's home directory, `/root`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the same directory you made the dump. It's ./myBackup.sql and not myBackup.sql
Do an ls -all.

Comment: addition: "pwd"-command would give the full path to the current directory and the location of the file

Answer (score 3):

It is in the same directory where you ran this command. To check this, run "pwd", it will give you your current path. Then run the command and it will store the database file in the same directory. 
To get generated file properly run following command,

```
mysqldump --database --user=root --password your_db_name > export_into_db.sql
```

This will give you the "export_into_db.sql" database file. 
Play with it.

Enjoy...

Answer (score 2):

It is at either at root or in current directory where you run the dump command.
try this command on terminal..

```
locate myBackup.sql
```

Comment: hmm.. locate myBackup.sql gives me nothing. Only find gives a result.  I can't find it in the top root folder (/.. where bin, boot, etc, var, etc... is located)... I check the "root" folder, and its not there either.

Comment: check in the directory where you run the dump command. OR take another dump again with command written below, this will create the dump at root (parallel to bin, boot, etc, var, etc)..

`root@xxxx:~# mysqldump -u root -p cherio > /myBackup.sql`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
It comes out that for some reason I could not create any file at root directory.
Try to go into some deeper folder
For example

```
cd var
cd www
```

and than execute:

```
mysqldump -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASE > backup.sql
```